# How do I close this JOptionPane upon clicking?

Tags: java, joptionpane

My JOptionPane shows up just fine, but when I click the button, nothing happens.  Once I click the 'X', the console will print which of the buttons was clicked.  It just won't close when the button is clicked:

```
final JOptionPane newDocWarning = new JOptionPane("Would you like to save before opening a new file?", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
final JDialog newDocDialog = new JDialog(this, "New Document", true);                

newDocDialog.setContentPane(newDocWarning);
newDocDialog.setSize(420, 150);
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 
newDocDialog.setLocation(dim.width/2-newDocDialog.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2- newDocDialog.getSize().height/2);
newDocDialog.setVisible(true);

int value = ((Integer)newDocWarning.getValue()).intValue();

if(value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    System.out.println("YES OPTION WAS CLICKED");
    newDocDialog.dispose();
}else if(value == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
    System.out.println("NO OPTION WAS CLICKED");
    newDocDialog.setVisible(false);
}else if(value == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
    System.out.println("CANCEL OPTION WAS CLICKED");
    newDocWarning.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the JOptionPane constructor? Why not simply use the static methods of the JOptionPane? They are easy and work well.

Comment: Are you referring to using this:

    String [] options = {"Yes", "No", "Cancel"};
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[2]);                

instead of the constructor?

Because I agree, that would be much easier, I just don't know how to code the buttons on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this one using [JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

```
int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
        "Would you like to save before opening a new file?", "New Document",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

In this case you don't need to close it. It will be automatically closed once any button is clicked.

For more info have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew there had to be some simple way of doing it! I can't believe I spent so much time trying to figure that out...

Comment: You are Welcome. Follow the link that I have mentioned in my post to learn more about it.